# SQL Server: a stored procedure to check incorrect data and send email if found

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure that checks for invalid year format - '0YYY' or '00YY' 0r '000Y' - and if found, the stored procedure sends out an email with the result.

The stored procedure works right now, but I need to make some changes. I need the stored procedure to ONLY send out the name and the incorrect dates and hide the correct dates like below.

```
name       Start_date     end_date
--------------------------------------
John       0019-12-01
Jane                       0020-01-05
Mike       0019-01-05      0019-12-01
```

The stored procedure looks like this right now.

```
Declare @count int

select @count = count(*)
from [Assign_Tbl] a
where (a.Assign_Thru_Da >= getdate() or a.Assign_Thru_Da is null 
       or (a.Assign_From_Da >= getdate() and a.Assign_Thru_Da >= getdate())
       or (a.Assign_From_Da <= getdate() and a.Assign_Thru_Da <= getdate())) 
  and ((a.Assign_From_Da like '0%' or a.Assign_From_Da like '00%' or a.Assign_From_Da like '000%')  
       or (a.Assign_Thru_Da like '0%' or a.Assign_Thru_Da like '00%' or a.Assign_Thru_Da like '000%'))

if @count > 0
begin
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        --@profile_name='emailFrsdata2',
        @recipients=N'won.chang@montgomerycountymd.gov',
        @subject = 'WFTS - Incorrect Assignment Dates found',
        @query = N'select r.RscMaster_Name_Ch as Name,  a.assign_from_da as Start_Date, a.Assign_Thru_Da as End_Date
                   from [Assign_Tbl] a
                   left join [Resource_Master_Tbl] r on r.RscMaster_No_In = a.RscMaster_No_In
                   where (a.Assign_Thru_Da >= getdate() or a.Assign_Thru_Da is null 
                          or (a.Assign_From_Da >= getdate() and a.Assign_Thru_Da >= getdate())
                          or (a.Assign_From_Da <= getdate() and a.Assign_Thru_Da <= getdate())) 
                     and ((a.Assign_From_Da like ''0%'' or a.Assign_From_Da like ''00%'' or a.Assign_From_Da like ''000%'')  
                          or (a.Assign_Thru_Da like ''0%'' or a.Assign_Thru_Da like ''00%'' or a.Assign_Thru_Da like ''000%''))
                   order by r.RscMaster_Name_Ch',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0
end
```

Comment: You should not store dates as strings, use one of the date/time data types. And instead of getting the `count()` and then check if it's larger than zero you can use `IF EXISTS (<your query>)`, that should be faster.

Comment: If you just used the right datatype you would have no need for this procedure in the first place. Or at the very least the query would be simple because you don't have to do all this insane checking of stuff.

Comment: Your last set of predicates are totally redundant. When you have like '0%' you don't also need to check for '00%' or '000%'. The first one captures all three.